# Can i restore some mysql database by just copying folder in Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have seen that i have folders corresponding to the databases i have in

`/var/lib/mysql/php_site1`

Now i want to know that i copy that folder and just paste inside other mysql, will it work or i need to do anything else as well

provided i have same setting

Comment: Avoid that, even if it is possible. You should always backup your MySQL data using `mysqldump` (and restore them). BTW, Linux have directories, not folders.

Comment: Well, I disagree with that. There is no reason why you shouldn´t do this as long as you know what you are doing. Most of the online backup solutions which are avaiable rely on copying data files and not dumping the entire database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, I assume that you use InnoDB tables, when you shutdown your mysql instance you can backup the files, make sure it includes the following:

- ibdata and *.ibd files
- *.frm files
- ib_log files
- my.cnf files

On the new machine make sure you make the adjustments in the my.cnf which suits your database layout. If you are not absolutely sure what you are doing, i would suggest to use a simple dump to archive your goal. I have seen many times where people tried to copy the database and where left with a useless db.

Also please read this part of the documentation carefully: [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html)

Comment: what is `innodb` and what ar eother types. how can find that